# InfluxDB - what's shard group duration

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I have created one year policy in InfluxDB and shard group duration was automatically set to 168h.

This is how my retentions look like now:

[image: Retentions]

This is how my shards look like now:

[image: Shards]

What does it mean for my data that shard's end time is set one week ahead?

Comment: Could you give me a clue how you set it to one year? As I only find week, no months, no years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that all of data written to database `st_test` and retention policy `a_year` with a timestamp between `2016-10-03` and `2016-10-10` will be stored in shard `16`.

A retention policy is a container for shards. Each shard in the retention policy will have `1w` worth of data. And after `1y` that shard will expire and we will remove it.

See the [shard documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#what-is-the-relationship-between-shard-group-durations-and-retention-policies) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

In order to understand `shard group durations`, you need to understand its relation with `retention policy duration`.

The **Retention policy DURATION** determines how long InfluxDB keeps the data. While **SHARD DURATION** clause determines the time range covered by a shard group.

A single shard group covers a specific time interval; InfluxDB determines that time interval by looking at the `DURATION` of the relevant retention policy (RP). The table below outlines the **default relationship** between the `DURATION` of an RP and the time interval of a shard group,

[image]

When you create a retention policy, you can modify that `shard duration`,

```
CREATE RETENTION POLICY <retention_policy_name> ON <database_name> DURATION <duration> REPLICATION <n> [SHARD DURATION <duration>] [DEFAULT]
```